# Terraform REST call for new DB

Tags: terraform

I have REST API to create new database cluster.

How to call the REST API from terraform to create a cluster? Should I write a customer provider?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what are you trying to do? What kind of database cluster and about the API call that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't have a lot of detail here is what I can provide to get you there. If this is a one off solution or you are just trying to figure it out, then I would suggest you use a [Null Resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) with a [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html).  You can then use Terraform to make your REST API calls using the command line.  Here is a rough example.

```
resource "null_resource" "rest-db"
{
     provisioner "local-exec" {
         inline = [
            "call the REST API here using CLI tools",
         ]
     }
}
```

You can even use the *depends_on* on the resource if you need to wait for another resource to be created before it runs.